# Summing a large spreadsheet on a date by date basis

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The spreadsheet consists of columns that include:

|start date|end date|power value|new column|

There are over 100,000 rows covering a two year period with ~96 row power values per starting date. My challenge is to sum up each day's total power values and insert that days total into a "new column" in the last row of each date series. I used to think I was pretty good at excel and VB but that was years ago and this relatively simple problem solution has eluded me for several days now.

Comment: What VBA have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: Have you looked into SUMIFS? You can use SUMIFS in combination with date ranges by stating from .. to something like this: `=SUMIFS(SumRange,DateRange,">="&Date,DateRange,"<="&Date)`

Comment: I read the problem differently than P.B's interpretation.  It may be easier to have one formula that you paste all the way down the new column, instead of having to go every 96-ish cells and find the date break.  So I was thinking in D5 you'd have: `=IF(A6<>A5, SUMIF(DateRange,A5,PowerRange),"")`  This assumes the data is sorted by start date or it won't work.

Comment: I think P.b got the proper approach but a few thing are unclear.  I guess each lines covers several dates, with `start date` and `end date` most probably different. So how would you link the new column to a specific day ? Let's say line one is (day/month/year) 1/1/22 | 3/1/22 | 10 and line 2 is 2/1/22 | 5/1/22 | 5. Basicaly the new power value per day should be 1/1/22 | 10 ; 2/1/22 | 15 ; 3/1/22 | 15 ; 4/1/22 | 5 ; 5/1/22 | 5. If you are looking at something like this, I would suggest to output the data in a different sheet (or in the same sheet, but with a blank column)

Comment: Thanks everyone! There are ~96 power values per day representing 15 minute intervals (the time stamps are in another colimn). So, for example row 97, + or -  one or two (for rare missed intervals, or duplicate readings), will be the start of a new day but 96 can not be relied for the # of samples per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find per day, the sum of power value, you'll need two columns :

1. One for the date
2. One for the sum

As you already have 3 columns (assuming Col A = start date, B = end date and C = power value) I'd suggest a blank column (D) and col E being `date`, col F being `power value sum`.

Then put the following formulas:

> E2 : =MIN(A:A) --> this will find the first start date

> E3 : =IF(E2+1>MAX(B:B),"",E2+1) --> will increment the day by 1 until it reach the maximum end day. From that point it will put a blank value

Deploy the formula until you got some empty cells

> F2 : =if(E2="","",SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<="&E2,B:B,">="&E2)) --> will sum the power values as long as the range start date - end date includes the date in column E, and force the value at blank when there are no more dates

Deploy the formula

Comment: Thanks @samuel! Late last night, using your suggestion, I came up with something very simular. Once that was working for the whole sheet I added another couple of columns, one for min power value and another for max. This morning the sheet is looking pretty good!